# implementation of mvvm architecture in objective-c

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to implement the mvvm architecture in objective-c ? I need sample project to learn the mvvm architecture and also i need to know that what is needed to give in model, view, viewModel and how to separate  in objective-c ? what is the difference between the normal project and mvvm project ?

Comment: Asking for a library, tutorial is not a valid topic here.  If you need a sample project, look for a tutorial online for yourserlf.

Comment: As @ElTomato says this is not a valid topic for here. Since I was looking for the same and found something interesting I share it here: https://github.com/colatusso/SimpleMVVM

Answer (score 3):

Jesto I can give you details about what you ask briefly.Even if it is explanation you can easily understand what I post here because it has sources with examples and you can directly try the source.

[First the Model](https://www.raywenderlich.com/132662/mvc-in-ios-a-modern-approach)

> The model layer is not as self-explanatory as it may seem.
>
> As you would expect, it will have your model objects, potentially
>   covering most of the layer surface. In the tickets example, you would
>   have a Ticket struct that would live in your model.
>
> I find the following components to also be part of the model layer:
>
> Network Code. The shape should be something like this. Ideally, you’d only use a single class for network communication across your
>   entire app.
>       Persistence Code. You would implement this with Core Data or simply by saving an NSData blob directly to disk.
>       Parsing Code. Any objects that parse network responses and the like should be included in the Model layer as well.
>
> While the model objects and the parser are domain-specific, the
>   network code will be highly reusable.
>
> The controller will then use all the elements in your model layer to
>   define the flow of information in your app.

[Second the View](https://www.raywenderlich.com/132662/mvc-in-ios-a-modern-approach)

> When a user interacts with your app, they are interacting with the
>   view layer. The view is considered the “dumb” part of your app, since
>   it shouldn’t contain any business logic. In code terms, you’ll
>   normally see:
>
> UIView subclasses. These range from a basic UIView to complex custom UI controls.
>    A UIViewController (arguably). Since a UIViewController is strongly coupled with its own root UIView and its different cycles
>   (loadView, viewDidLoad), I personally consider it to be part of this
>   layer, but not everyone agrees.
>    Animations and UIViewController transitions.
>    Classes that are part of UIKit/AppKit, Core Animation and Core Graphics.
>
> Typical code smells found in this layer manifest in different ways,
>   but boil down to including anything unrelated to UI in your view
>   layer. A classic code smell is making a network call from a
>   UIViewController.
>
> It’s tempting to put a bunch of code in your UIViewController and be
>   done with it, so you can meet that deadline. Don’t do it! In the short
>   term, you might save a couple of minutes, but in the long term, you
>   could lose hours looking for a bug, or have trouble when you want to
>   reuse code inside one view controller in another.

[Third MVVM](https://www.raywenderlich.com/132662/mvc-in-ios-a-modern-approach)

> Model-View-ViewModel, or MVVM, is an MVC derivation. Conceptually,
>   it’s similar. The biggest difference is in the communication between
>   layers, and instead of a controller, you use a view model.
>
> In practice, MVVM shines when it has an FRP framework to support it.
>   Since the model is now observed by the view model and the view model
>   by the view, the FRP paradigm becomes a natural choice to manage the
>   information flow. This leads to a better separation between layers,
>   which translates in decoupled components that are easy to test.
>
> Bottom line: architecture is important, but in my opinion the right
>   programming paradigm will influence more the overall quality of your
>   code. It’s also important to note, that most often that not, you will
>   have in the same app different approaches. This includes both
>   architecture and paradigm. You might think this will disrupt
>   consistency inside the codebase, but you should always use the right
>   tool for the job.

[Finally MVC](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/MVC.html)

> The Model-View-Controller (MVC) design pattern assigns objects in an
>   application one of three roles: model, view, or controller. The
>   pattern defines not only the roles objects play in the application, it
>   defines the way objects communicate with each other. Each of the three
>   types of objects is separated from the others by abstract boundaries
>   and communicates with objects of the other types across those
>   boundaries. The collection of objects of a certain MVC type in an
>   application is sometimes referred to as a layer—for example, model
>   layer.
>
> MVC is central to a good design for a Cocoa application. The benefits
>   of adopting this pattern are numerous. Many objects in these
>   applications tend to be more reusable, and their interfaces tend to be
>   better defined. Applications having an MVC design are also more easily
>   extensible than other applications. Moreover, many Cocoa technologies
>   and architectures are based on MVC and require that your custom
>   objects play one of the MVC roles.

[Difference between Normal and MVVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4581000/what-are-the-differences-between-presenter-presentation-model-viewmodel-and-co)

> **Models** — responsible for the domain data or a data access layer 
>   which manipulates the data, think of ‘Person’ or ‘PersonDataProvider’
>   classes.
>
> **Views** — responsible for the presentation layer (GUI), for iOS environment think of everything starting with ‘UI’ prefix.
>
> **Controller/Presenter/ViewModel** — the glue or the mediator between the Model and the View, in general responsible for altering the Model
>   by reacting to the user’s actions performed on the View and updating
>   the View with changes from the Model.

[MVVM Says](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52)

> The latest and the greatest of the MV(X) kind The MVVM is the newest
>   of MV(X) kind thus, let’s hope it emerged taking into account problems
>   MV(X) was facing previously. In theory the Model-View-ViewModel looks
>   very good. The View and the Model are already familiar to us, but also
>   the Mediator, represented as the View Model. MVVM It is pretty similar
>   to the MVP:
>   the MVVM treats the view controller as the View
>   There is no tight coupling between the View and the Model In addition, it does binding like the Supervising version of the MVP;
>   however, this time not between the View and the Model, but between the
>   View and the View Model. So what is the View Model in the iOS reality?
>   It is basically UIKit independent representation of your View and its
>   state. The View Model invokes changes in the Model and updates itself
>   with the updated Model, and since we have a binding between the View
>   and the View Model, the first is updated accordingly.

Also [the MVVM Design Pattern](https://www.captechconsulting.com/blogs/ios-design-patterns-mvc-and-mvvm) and [How does MVVM work?](https://dzone.com/articles/comparing-mvvm-and-viper-architectures-when-to-use)

Answer (score 2):

Check it out this topic -> [What is the difference between MVC and MVVM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/667781/what-is-the-difference-between-mvc-and-mvvm)

Model-View-ViewModel basic example is here -> https://github.com/futurice/mvvm-example-objc and maybe next step, you can use reactive cocoa because it can be more effective with mvvm -> https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveViewModel

reactive cocoa -> https://github.com/ReactiveCocoa/ReactiveCocoa

goodluck :)